# Edit summaries are truncated in reopen reviews

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

I recently [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53165582/revisions) which I thought had been incorrectly marked as a duplicate. However, the reviewers declined to reopen it. Fair enough, it wasn't a great question, and maybe they thought it should stay closed for other reasons.

But then I saw on the [review history page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21348184) that my edit summary has been truncated, so my assertion that it isn't a duplicate isn't visible.

Is this how it looks in the actual review UI? Surely reviewers should have access to the entire edit summary when making their decision.

Comment: I mean.. it's surprising if it's not a dupe (tangential to your question here): the fact that 'community' marked it as dupe means the OP themselves agreed the dupe answers their question...  (But yeah I agree your edit summary shouldn't be cut like that)

Comment: The OP is a new user and doesn't necessarily know what they are doing.

Comment: Hovering it does not help to show the summary either.

Comment: Edit summaries are not where you should be explaining that it's not a duplicate. Such explanations should go *in the question*, often at the top, or in a comment on the question (less good).

Comment: However, it being a "specific question about a specific product" by itself doesn't make it not a duplicate of the generic solution (that's why it's a *generic/general* solution). Also note, IIRC, that the question being closed by Community♦ indicates that the OP confirmed that the duplicate was valid and solved their problem.